# How can we hide the footer on the specific page in SSRS?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I want to hide footer of second page in ssrs report and other page should have the footer. Is this possible to hide footer to specific page in SSRS?

I looked in expression but there is no specific expression available for the visibility for footer. Can any body help on this?

Comment: Do you only have two pages? You may be able to set the `PrintOnFirstPage` property to `True` and the `PrintOnLastPage` property to `False`.

Comment: No I have lots of pages all are dynamic

Answer (score 1):

Add a rectangle to your footer and put all your content in it.

Set the visibility settings of that rectangle to the following:

```
=iif(Globals!PageNumber=2,true,false)
```